# Are these examples correct?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

In [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/cc16ShyiUG8?list=PLRJhV4hUhIymmp5CCeIFPyxbknsdcXCc8&t=563), I came across with the following examples:

[image]

However, they doesn't seem correct to me, for the first example:

```
*ptr++
```

In my understanding, this means that, if `++` has greated precedence than `*`, increment the pointer by 1 in pointer arithmetic, then get the value stored in the address which is pointed by this new pointer. So the code

```
x = *ptr++;
```

should be equal to,

```
ptr++;
x = *ptr;
```

Which is either conflicting with the video, or I am mixing somethings. Can you please tell me if I am right or wrong?

Comment: No, `ptr++` is *post*-increment.

Comment: @WeatherVane oops, yes.... thank you

Comment: Where precedence relates is as in the graphic, so that `(*ptr)++` uses the parentheses to override the precedence, to increment the data not the pointer.

Comment: please don't edit questions to say "solved". Instead, accept a posted answer, or if there are none then you can write one yourself

Comment: @WeatherVane could not exactly understand your last comment

Comment: The `*ptr++` reads data from the address pointed to, and then increments the pointer. The `(*ptr)++` increments the data beign pointed to. All as the graphic. The parentheses force the compiler to apply the `++` increment to `*ptr` instead of to `ptr`.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but why didn't you just try to execute the code?

Comment: @klutt nothing would change, I would come and ask another question with a title starting with "Why". I was just like never knew the fact that `var++;` will increment the value of `var` after that line of code.

Comment: @muyustan Well, you could have discovered that the video was wrong. But for the record. It doesn't get incremented after that line of code. It does get incremented during that line, but the return value of the expression `var++` is the value that `var` had before the operation. Doesn't matter in this context, but with multithreading it can.

Comment: @muyustan And one consequence of that is that expressions like `x + x++` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Precedence affects how expressions are structured. It does not affect what the rules of the operations are.

In `*ptr++`, precedence says the rules for `++` are applied to `ptr`, and then the rules for `*` are applied to the result.

The rules for `++` say that, with `ptr++`, the resulting value is that of `ptr` when the operation starts and, separately, the value of `ptr` is incremented. The actual increment of `ptr` in memory may occur before, during, or after the production of the result value, but it does not affect the value: The value produced is always the value of `ptr` before the increment, regardless of when the increment actually occurs.

The rules for `*` say the result is the object that its operand points to. So, with `*ptr++`, the result is the object that `ptr` points to before the increment is applied.

Comment: Good point about "increment of ptr in memory may occur before, during, or after the production of the result value"

Answer (score 1):

Each expression if it is not a void expression has a value.

The value of the postfix increment is the value of its operand before incrementing.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
>   operand**. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
>   incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
>   it)

That is this expression

```
*ptr++
```

is evaluated like

```
*( ptr++ )
```

and the value of the expression in the parentheses is the value of the pointer (the operand of the postfix increment) before incrementing of the operand itself that is evaluated as a side effect.

This is the difference between the postfix increment and the prefix increment for which (6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented.
>   **The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation**.

It is useful to know that the postfix increment operator may be used to form  a subscript expression while the prefix increment operator may not.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };
    int *p = &a[0];

    printf( "a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d\n", a[0], a[1] );

    p++[0] = 3;
    *p = 4;

    printf( "a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d\n", a[0], a[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a[0] = 1, a[1] = 2
a[0] = 3, a[1] = 4
```